# How to print log in pytest using AWS Chalice framework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, logging, chalice

How to print log in `pytest` using `AWS Chalice` framework?

The log prints everything if we use custom logger

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Run test with log-level (Working)

```
pytest --log-cli-level=DEBUG
```

If I use `AWS chalice log`

```
import logging

from chalice import Chalice

app = Chalice(app_name='demolog')
# Enable DEBUG logs.
app.log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    app.log.debug("This is a debug statement")
return {'hello': 'world'}
```

The same test command is not printing any log

```
pytest --log-cli-level=DEBUG
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Sure your Chalice instance is in debug and you can also turn off configure_logs

```
app=Chalice(app_name="MyApp", debug=True, configure_logs=False)
```

Put your debug and configure_logs on environment variables and then you can control them based on local/dev/stage/prod environments.

Answer (score 0):

```
from chalice import Chalice
import logging

app = Chalice(app_name='eballot-poll-role')
# Log
app.debug = True
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```